# Need to log in LastPass every browser start

Tags: lastpass

If I close down Chrome I have to log in again with LastPass extension next time I start Chrome. That wastes a lot of my precious time.

Anyone have a solution?

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Preferably a solution that still make computer restarts *always* make me have to log in again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check both Remeber Email and Remember Password in order to have it automatically login.

If that doesn't work, remove the LastPass plugin, then clear everything in Chrome (cache, etc...), close Chrome, check task manager to verify all instances are closed, then reopen, then add LastPass again, and login with those checks set.

Comment: Ah, that's an option. But if I allow someone to use my computer and I have the password stored then they will have access to all my passwords. One way to get around that is to set stuff up so that guests use some other Windows account that don't have my Chrome passwords, but I hope that there is a better, faster, easier solution.

Comment: So you want it to always log you in... except when you don't. You really can't have it both ways. Golden Rule: Don't allow other people to use your computer. if you must, then set them up with their own account, or make them use a guest account.

Comment: @Tetsujin `So you want it to always log you in`.I want the log in to be remembered even if I close the browser and a possibility to log out. `You really can't have it both ways.` It would be possible if the LastPass login was remembered in an external app/program. The problem arises from me using the LastPass browser extension to log in, and it forgets the log in when I close the browser.

Comment: @fredrik.hjarner yes, it can't login because it doesn't know the password. You have to save the password in the extension (which is the checkbox) so that it can automatically login for you. There really is no other way. You want chrome to auto login, make sure the password is remembered. If you know on beforehand that guests are coming, you can always choose to logout from the lastpass extension. Next time you login, you set the checkbox again.